# remove choose an option dropdown from woocommerce product category page

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove product variations form from product category page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

```
<?php
if ( is_product() ) 
{
?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( stripslashes( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php

```
<?php
if(is_product()) 
{
?>
<div class="quantity">
<input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>" />
</div>
<? } ?>
```

woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php

```
<?php
if(is_product()) 
{
?>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <?php
        /**
         * @since 3.0.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
        ) );

        /**
         * @since 3.0.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
    ?>
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Add font icon to add to cart text

```
function filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $quantity, $product ) 
{ 


    return sprintf('<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;%s</a>',

    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text()),$product );

}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
```